# certificate of deposit formula in java

Tags: java

How can i add years to this formula. I am trying to get the maturity outta certificate of deposit. The sample formula is 80000(1 + 7.75 / 100)to the power of years(15)

```
maturity = amountDeposited * (1 + interestRate / 100);
```

Comment: If interest rate is an int you'll get a bad answer as i/100 will be 0 for all values < 100. You'd be safer using /100.0 to force a floating point answer

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the whole equation to the power of, then:

```
double years = 15;
Math.pow(maturity, years);
```

If you mean just the bracketed portion, then:

```
double years = 15;
double maturity = amountDeposited * (Math.pow((1 + interestRate / 100), years));
```